# Obtaining and using values in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

In the JSP page, I would ask a couple of questions in a particular order, for which the answer is a yes or no or no selection. I need to create an int array where these choices are stored in the exact same order, 1 for yes, 0 for no, null for no response.

The problem is that I should obtain the values, and when the user clicks submit, I should not leave the page, but instead use that array in a java function in the JSP.

Please tell me what concept I need to learn, and where to look.

Thank you

Comment: using ajax maybe ?

Comment: In your case Ajax is the ideal solution. When the user clicks on "Submit", you execute an AjaxRequest and send the value of the variable to your Java backend controller. There you execute the logic for further processing and can return the results as a response of the AjaxReqeust and process them with JavaScript (display message, show validation errors, etc.)